# It takes too long to read data from the bluetooth chip

Tags: android, bluetooth, inputstream

I'm working on a project which using `bluetooth` to send two bytes data to `HC-05` `module` and receive from it. Everything is going well but there's one thing that I can't bear with, which is stated below.

I use **`System.currentTimeMills()`** to get the time interval between sending data and receiving ,and it takes no more than ``` 1ms`` to detect whether there's data in the buffer of ```inputStream`. However, it takes about`30~200ms`to read`two bytes`of data from the`bluetooth` chip on my cell phone.

Dose anyone know how to reduce the time ? Or it's  insolvable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The primary bottleneck should be the protocol scheduling. I don't know how this particular module works, but in Bluetooth in general you have to wait for your timeslot to send or receive.

Suggestions:

- Check if you can send more than 2 bytes at the time. The read time is stable, but you get more data transmitted each time.
- Check if the API gives you scheduling options, so the wait time goes down.
- For your use case I think things would be simpler with Bluetooth low energy (BLE). You will need another module, but IMO it is worth it.

Comment: I can send more than 2 bytes, but the mcu which receives the data can only handle one byte of data each time and doesn't have a buffer to store.
I've used a ble module at first, but the module has another problem